# Why is this JavaScript and html code not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a JavaScript code that solves the midpoint formula when you give it inputs but when it gives me the answer the numbers are not what they are supposed to be! I have checked everything and it should work fine, but it doesn't. Here is the code,please help me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var xone = document.getElementById("x1").value;
            var yone = document.getElementById("y1").value;
            var xtwo = document.getElementById("x2").value;
            var ytwo = document.getElementById("y2").value;
            var step1 = (xone + xtwo) / 2;
            var step2 = (yone + ytwo) / 2;
            alert("(" + step1 + "," + step2 + ")");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span>x1</span>
    <input type="text" id="x1"></input><br>
    <span>y1</span>
    <input type="text" id="y1"></input><br>
    <span>x2</span>
    <input type="text" id="x2"></input><br>
    <span>y2</span>
    <input type="text" id="y2"></input><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "numbers are not what they are supposed to be". What numbers are you seeing and what did you expect them to be?

Comment: That's what you get when trying to calculate with strings.

Comment: the problem is that if you put 10 everywhere, you should obtain 20 / 2 = 10 and he obtain 505 (10 + 10 = 1010 => 1010:2 = 505)

Answer (score 0):

here is the correction

```
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var xone =  document.getElementById("x1").value;
        var yone = document.getElementById("y1").value; 
        var xtwo =  document.getElementById("x2").value;
        var ytwo = document.getElementById("y2").value;
        var step1= (+xone + +xtwo)/2;
        var step2= (+yone + +ytwo)/2;
        alert("("+step1+","+step2+")");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span>x1</span>
<input type="text" id="x1"></input><br>
<span>y1</span>
<input type="text" id="y1"></input><br>
<span>x2</span>
<input type="text" id="x2"></input><br>
<span>y2</span> 
<input type="text" id="y2"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
</body>
```

You try to add the 2 number. For this you should do +var1 + +var2